# Free XML Editor for OS X

Tags: xml, macos

Are there any free XML editors for OS X? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950/xml-editor-for-os-x) question, but none of the answers are free. I don't need to be able to do anything complicated, just view and edit XML in a friendly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking around, it looks like [Serna](http://www.syntext.com/products/serna-free/) is the consensus for XML. I, however, use [Smultron](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/).

Comment: oops, wrong link. I was trying to install the enterprise version

Answer (score 3):

I used [Serna Free XML Editor](http://www.syntext.com/products/serna-free/) (Note they do have a free version) when I was doing some programming with XML in OSX.

Comment: New link for [Serna Free](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sernafree.mirror/).  It looks like Serna was bought out and the new company doesn't provide the free version.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs run in OS X, has an XML mode, and is Free (as in speech).  It might be kind of heavy-weight if all you want is basic syntax highlighting, indentation, etc.